# Log4j2 - Get appender filter programmatically

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am currently upgrading a project from using log4j1 to log4j2.
There are places in the code where calls to *appender.getFilter()* are being made which are no longer available using the new API.
Old code used *org.apache.log4j.Appender* and I am now currently using *org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Appender*.

Checking the log4j2 documentation and code I can see that filters can be added to Appenders but I am not able to find how to get them.

Is there a way to programmatically get a filter which has been applied to an Appender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getFilter()` is still there, but it has been removed from the [`Appender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/Appender.html) interface: an appender is not required to support filters, although all those standard ones do.

To retrieve the filter you just need to cast to [`Filterable`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/filter/Filterable.html):

```java
final Filter filter = appender instanceof Filterable ?
                      ((Filterable) appender).getFilter() :
                      null;
```

**Remark**: in Log4j 2.x filters can appear in four different locations (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html)).